Как решить задачу: продублировать строку, пока итоговая длина не превысит 100
name = input("Your name: ")
while len(name) > 100:
    print(name)
    name *=1 

Я так написал, но код неверный. 
Мне нужно дублировать имя до 100.
Я не понимаю, нужно чтобы было вот так:
#1 Маша 
#2 МашаМаша
#3 МашаМашаМаша
#так далее я не понимаю как написать код. 


for i in range(100//len(name)): print(name*(i+1))

Спасибо за помощь.

while len(name) <=100 : name *= 2

@Vitalizzare Я бы хотел что-то прояснить, я только учусь Пайтону.  Это для меня все новое.  Эта задача была дана мне после урока как домашняя работа.  Просидев над ней несколько часов, у меня получался код с ошибками или не так, как нужно.  Потом я решил написать сюда.  Чтобы люди, работающие в этом направлении, помогли мне и объяснили как решить задачу.  Я благодарю тебя за помощь, в следующий раз, когда буду формировать вопрос о задаче, я постараюсь описать все гораздо подробнее.

str_ = input('Введите строку')
str1 = ''
if str_:
    while len(str1) < 100:
        str1 += str_
        print(str1)
    print(str1)
else:
    print('Ошибка!')


Задачка весьма забавная. Она отучает Python разработчиков от ненужной итерации.
Мне нужно дублировать имя до 100. Превысит 100, то-есть будет длиннее 100. Например 101 подойдет.
В этой задаче цикл вовсе не нужен, он только нагромождает код!
Я хоть и очень плохо знаю py, но решил-бы её например вот так.
Имя повторять пока (100 делить на длину имени) и добавить 1 что-бы было больше ста.
Если конечно длинна есть?
Иначе "Пусто!"

name = input("Your name: ")
print(name * int(100/len(name)+1) if len(name) > 0 else "Пусто!")

Если всё-же нужен каждый шаг итерации, то можно и развернуть пример:
name = input("Your name: ")
if len(name) > 0:
    for i in range(1, int(100/len(name))+1):
        print(i, name * i)
    i += 1
    print(i, name * i)
else:
    print("Пусто!")


Кстати, умные люди, напомните пожалуйста inline инкремент в Py как делался? i++ и ++i а то чёт когда пример делал, не вспомнил.

Это делается так: i += 1. В питоне нет ++

len(name) - считает количество символов в имени, для этой задачи это неправильно
# будет выполняться пока количество букв в name больше 100
# то есть цикл не рабочий изначально
while len(name) > 100: 
    # просто выводит имя
    print(name)
    # can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
    name +=1 

Корректное решение
Через while:
count = 1
while count < 100:
    print(name * count)
    count += 1

Через for:
for count in range(100):
    print(name * count)


Спасибо за объяснение я понял в чем проблема.

@Vitalizzare итоговая длина должна быть меньше 100, если я правильно понял условие

@Vitalizzare дублирование до тех пор пока вся длина не превысит 100.

@Vitalizzare длина равна 100 и программа закрывается.

@Vitalizzare #1 Маша #2 МашаМаша #3 МашаМашаМаша и так далее... до 100  потом конец
